# Exceptions that are not thrown

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-8, exception

I have checked the default exceptions in Debug->Exceptions but when I run my Win8 app I get these in the Output and nothing happens? How to even debug this thing?

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in XXX.exe
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in XXX.exe
>   Blockquote

EDIT:

So this is the scenario. I have a windows phone application with two pages. From Page1 I navigate to Page2 by clicking a button. In Page2 the constructor is this:

```
public Page2()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
    this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;

    this.DataContext = new CompositeViewModel();
}
```

I set a breakpoint on the opening bracket of the constructor and move down with F10. When I reach and pass this line:

```
this.DataContext = new CompositeViewModel();
```

I get these two exceptions in the Output, and the app stays on Page1, without even showing Page2, so yes nothing happens. When I comment this line I can see Page2. The weird thing is the other day there wasn' t this problem, and this morning I start my PC then boom.. what the hell?

Comment: Do they interrupt your program's execution? Because these aren't necessarily "bad" exceptions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? nothing happens as in your program runs as normal or nothing happens as everything freezes or nothing happens as in the program does not start?

Comment: First chance exceptions are not normally a problem - it's likely that something is catching them so they don't get escalated to second chance.

Comment: Can you debug into the `CompositeViewModel` constructor?

Comment: They are pretty gross exceptions, having them swallowed is pretty likely to have an adverse side-effect.  Use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.  The debugger now unconditionally stops when the exception is thrown.  This won't necessarily stop the program in a happy place with source code, be sure to look at the Call Stack debugger window.

Comment: Yes I debugged the ViewModel constructor. There was the problem. But how to get my IDE stops with exception on the exact problem line? What to check in Debug->Exceptions